# How does one 'vote' for a release codename?

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-wiki

So I know there are questions similar to this but they don't answer this question of where can i go and vote for a codename and/or suggest one. So, does anybody know an actual url with which I can accomplish this?

Comment: I dont think standard users get to vote on the codenames...

Answer (score 5):

There is a survey on OMG Ubuntu (http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/10/ten-years-ubuntu-user-survey) but it is unofficial.  Mark Shuttleworth actually picks the code name himself, based on which attributes he thinks the release should embody.  Although he may consider input, there is actually no "voting" for the release name.

Answer (score 2):

You can add your suggestion by editing this Ubuntu wiki page: [Development Code Names](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DevelopmentCodeNames#Code_Name_Suggestions). I don't think you can vote on them though.